# Setting credentials for a WCF application?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I've written a simple Application that utilizes WCF to communicate between client and server. When I run it locally it works fine, however when I run the server and client on two different boxes I get the following exception:

```
Unexpected error occured, while getting the group names from the VDN server
System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityNegotiationException: The server has rejected the client credentials.
System.Security.Authentication.InvalidCredentialException: The server has rejected the client credentials.
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The logon attempt failed
```

What are the credentials that are not being accepted? And how can I set them?

Is there a way to configure the server to not require authentication? The application is a simple monitoring app to security is not really an issue.

**Sorry about not being very specific:**
The app uses a pipe proxy and there is no wcf config file as the wcf code is hand coded.

My WCF code is based on the code in this tutorial:
http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/wcf-tutorial-basic-interprocess-communication

I didn't konw it was standard proctice to generate the wcf classes from a config till after I'd finished writing all the code. Now whenever I look at a tutorial/ help doc they use generated code and everything requires changing the config.

I don't have the bandwidth (I'm juggling 3 projects already) to replace my wcf component with one tht uses generated code but I will make sure to use the code generation next time I use wcf.

Comment: I think you need to be more specific. What's the binding you are using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a method like this...

```
void SetImpersonation(ref IServiceClient proxy)
{
  proxy.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.Domain = "MYDOMAIN";
  proxy.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.UserName = "A_USER";
  proxy.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.Password = "P4SSW0RD";
}
```

and call it when you create the new client class.

```
IServiceClient proxy = new IServiceClient ();
SetImpersonation(ref proxy);
```

Obvously, this is setting the information to be a specific user, and has security implications if your code is decompiled, but it should work in your (config file-less scenario)

Comment: I can migrate those values into the app.config. I just don't have a config file for the wcf code.

Thanks though that looks good.

Comment: how can avoid setting this in every using of my client ? Is there a way to set this for all clients in my solution?

Answer (score 11):

Here's a solution I found in a search for disabling wcf security/authentication.

From [MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wcf/thread/0aa606b7-171e-4c00-9dd6-6c635f96d906):

```
WSHttpBinding b = new WSHttpBinding();

b.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.None;
```

or add the following in config:

```
<wsHttpBinding>

    <binding name="myBinding">

        <security mode="None" />

    </binding>

</wsHttpBinding>
```

Comment: You have to be careful jumping to use this solution because the original exception could stem from a binding configuration using Windows Authentication. In that case blindly removing the security is a bad idea.  Check my answer at the bottom in the case of using Windows Authentication.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a WCF binding configuration with the following security:

```
<transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
```

then you will need to explicitly set the Windows Credentials on the WCF instance created in code like below:

```
'Create an instance of the WCF service      
Dim MyService As New MyWCFServiceClient

'Build credentials object for which this WCF call will be made
MyService.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential = New System.Net.NetworkCredential("UserName", "Password", "DomainName")

'Call a method on the service
MyService.MyMethod1()
```